# Calculating The Percentage Change Between Two Numbers

Tags: php, math

Looking for some clarification on below code for calculating the percentage change between two different number of which the original could be a greater or smaller number. So will this code work for showing either a increase + or a decrease - change? Thanks.

```
$original= 100;
$current = 95;

$percentChange = (1 - $original / $current ) * 100;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Just enter a larger number and you'll see.

Comment: Isn't it math question rather than programming?

Comment: I was able to use a online php sandbox and it looks good to me, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find difference and then count percentage like this

```
<?php
    $original= 100;
    $current = 115;
    $diff = $current - $original;
    $more_less = $diff > 0 ? "More" : "Less";
    $diff = abs($diff);
    $percentChange = ($diff/$original)*100;
    echo "$percentChange% $more_less agaist $original";
?>
```

Difference will be same for `110` and `90` against `100`

Live demo : https://eval.in/872926

Comment: Thanks Dude, I like the more/less switch I will use that with a +/-

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to thank you anyways. I was originally using the formula in the problem stated as many websites recommend it, but that solution is flawed. If there is a -100% change dividing by 0 will always return undefined, so it will not tell you a -100% change, The solution in this post is the correct way.

Answer (score 8):

This function is more useful because it is protects from division by zero, the output is roundable, and it handles both positive (increase) and negative (decrease) return values.

```php
if (! function_exists('pct_change')) {
    /**
     * Generate percentage change between two numbers.
     *
     * @param int|float $old
     * @param int|float $new
     * @param int $precision
     * @return float
     */
    function pct_change($old, $new, int $precision = 2): float
    {
        if ($old == 0) {
            $old++;
            $new++;
        }

        $change = (($new - $old) / $old) * 100;

        return round($change, $precision);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work for showing either a increase + or a decrease - change.